# how check position of clicked <li> with another inner ul <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `ul` with two inner `li`. I want to get the position of of the first `li`
but it counts all of the `li`

```js
$("#clicked_job li").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="clicked_job">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    <ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    <ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not a clear question. please include an example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop triggering the event of parent `li`. With this your code works fine and give the proper index of inner `li` with only one alert.

```js
$("#clicked_job li").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var index = $(this).index();
  alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="clicked_job">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your HTML is invalid. You're missing several closing tags, and instead have opened new tags.

Secondly, as you have nested the `li` tags you need to call `stopPropagation()` on the event that's raised in order to stop the event bubbling up the DOM. Try this:

```js
$("#clicked_job li").click(function(e) {  
  e.stopPropagation();
  var index = $(this).index();
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="clicked_job">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the html tags is example.and I try this solution but doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide more information than simply 'it doesn't work' - you can plainly see from the snippet above that this does work. Why does it not achieve what you require? Please be clearer in what your end result should be.